# Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

In Spark, it is possible to set some hadoop configuration settings like, e.g.

```
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.dfs.replication", "1")
```

This works, the replication factor is set to 1.
Assuming that this is the case, I thought that this pattern (prepending "spark.hadoop." to a regular hadoop configuration property), would also work for the
textinputformat.record.delimiter:

```
System.setProperty("spark.hadoop.textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n\n")
```

However, it seems that spark just ignores this setting.
Do I set the `textinputformat.record.delimiter` in the correct way?
Is there a simpler way of setting the `textinputformat.record.delimiter`. I would like to avoid writing my own `InputFormat`, since I really only need to obtain records delimited by two newlines.

Comment: What version of hadoop are you using?

Comment: I'm using the prebuilt version of spark-0.7.2 with Hadoop 1 / CDH3 (see [here](http://spark-project.org/downloads/)). I'm pretty sure that it was in fact built with hadoop 1.0.4

Comment: I'm not sure that it's in that version of hadoop, you might have to recompile yourself to a version that supports what you want: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7096

Answer (score 9):

I got this working with plain uncompressed files with the below function.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

def nlFile(path: String) = {
    val conf = new Configuration
    conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n")
    sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
      .map(_._2.toString)
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the hadoop core version you were using.

Comment: @SumitKumarGhosh that was with CDH 4.4 I believe.

Comment: Got it looks like it needs specific releases Hadoop 0.23.x, and 2.x versions - 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330447/paragraph-processing-for-hadoop/12351209#12351209)

I used the following maven dependency -
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>`

    this is good too -
    
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>`