# spark textfile load file instead of lines

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

In Spark, we can use textFile to load file into lines and try to do some operations with these lines as follows.

```
val lines = sc.textFile("xxx")
val counts = lines.filter(line => lines.contains("a")).count()
```

However, in my situation, I would like to load the file into blocks because the data in files and the block will be kind of as follow. Blocks will be separated with empty line in files.

```
user: 111
book: 222
comments: like it!
```

Therefore, I hope the textFile function or any other solutions can help me load the file with blocks, which may be achieved as follows.

```
val blocks = sc.textFile("xxx", 3 line)
```

Does anyone face this situation before? Thanks

Comment: What do you want to get exactly instead of `RDD[String]` which is the return type of `textFile` method?

Comment: How do you detect end of block? Do you have some special separator?

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari return type is RDD[String]

Comment: I think maybe I can group the result lines into groups

Comment: Yes, grouping is the most natural solution, if that works for your requirement.

Comment: @NaderHadjiGhanbari let me have a try, thank u.

Comment: @kylejan I think you'll have problem if you try to group lines after reading them because of distributed processing. On a single node, it's ok. On multiple nodes, one block could be split in 2 halves, the first half given to one node, the second half to another.

Comment: @GQuintana I will make an indexWithValue RDD firstly. And then group into new RDD with indexes bound

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to implement your own file reader function from Hdfs. Look at`textFile` function, it's built on top of `hadoopFile` function and it uses `TextInputFormat`:

```
def textFile(path: String, minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions): RDD[String] = {
    assertNotStopped()
    hadoopFile(path, classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text],
      minPartitions).map(pair => pair._2.toString).setName(path)
  }
```

But this `TextInputFormat` can be customized via hadoop properties as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692857/setting-textinputformat-record-delimiter-in-spark). In your case delimiter could be:

```
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n\n")
```