# Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in sparksql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark2.0.1 ,hadoop2.6.0, I have many files delimited with '!@!\r' and not with the usual new line \n,for example:

```
=========================================

2001810086  rongq   2001    810!@!
2001810087  hauaa   2001    810!@!
2001820081  hello   2001    820!@!
2001820082  jaccy   2001    820!@!
2002810081  cindy   2002    810!@!

=========================================
```

I try to extracted data according to [Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692857/setting-textinputformat-record-delimiter-in-spark)
`set textinputformat.record.delimiter='!@!\r';`or `set textinputformat.record.delimiter='!@!\n`';but still cannot extracted the data

In spark-sql,I do this :
===== ================================

```
create table ceshi(id int,name string, year string, major string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by '\t';

load data local inpath '/data.txt' overwrite into table ceshi;
select count(*) from ceshi;
```

the result is 5,but I try to `set textinputformat.record.delimiter='!@!\r'`; then `select count(*) from ceshi;` the result is 1, the delimiter donot work well;

I also check the source of hadoop2.6.0, the method of RecordReader in TextInputFormat.java,I notice that default textinputformat.record.delimiter is null,then the the LineReader.java use the method readDefaultLine to read a line terminated by one of CR, LF, or CRLF(CR ='\r',LF ='\n').

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sparkContext`'s `hadoopConfiguration` api to set the `textinputformat.record.delimiter` as

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "!@!\r")
```

Then if you read the text file using `sparkContext` as

```
sc.textFile("the input file path")
```

You should fine.

**Updated**

I have noticed that a text file with delimiter `\r` when saved is changed to `\n` delimiter.

so, following format should work for you as it did for me

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "!@!\n")
val data = sc.textFile("the input file path")
val df = data.map(line => line.split("\t"))
.map(array => ceshi(array(0).toInt, array(1), array(2), array(3)))
.toDF
```

a `case clas`s called `ceshi` is needed as

```
case class ceshi(id: Int, name: String, year: String, major :String)
```

which should give dataframe as

```
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
|id        |name |year |major|
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
|2001810086|rongq| 2001|810  |
|2001810087|hauaa| 2001|810  |
|2001820081|hello| 2001|820  |
|2001820082|jaccy| 2001|820  |
|2002810081|cindy| 2002|810  |
+----------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now you can hit the `count` function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(count("*")).show(false)
```

which would give output as

```
+--------+
|count(1)|
+--------+
|5       |
+--------+
```

Comment: ，hi, according to your help ,I try to set the parameter in spark-shell,use the peopel.txt in examples, but the result is not well; scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "!@!\r")

scala> val sb = sc.textFile("file:///data/people.txt")
sb: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///home/mr/ych/data/people.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> sb.first()

res1: String =
"Michael, 29!@!
Andy, 30!@!
Justin, 19!@!
"

scala> sb.count()
res2: Long = 1