# File with single Line around 4G to load into Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, io, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load a file which is a single line, there are no new line charters in the entire File so technical single line size is the size of the file. I tried to use the below code to load the data.

```
val data= spark.sparkContext.textFile("location") 
data.count
```

It is not able to return any value.

Tried to read the file as string with the following Code, Trying to write in java code.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
val inputPath = new Path("File")
val conf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
  val inputStream = fs.open(inputPath)
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
val readLines = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).readLine()
```

The JVM is getting exited with following error.

ava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007fcb6ba00000, 2148532224, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)

There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
 Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 2148532224 bytes for committing reserved memory.

**The Problem is entire data is in single line, spark using \n to identify the new record(new line). As there is \n it is trying to load into single line which creating the memory issues**

I am ok to split that long string based on length, add new line character for every 200 charcter (0,200) first line. (200,400) is second line.

Sample Input

```
This is Achyuth This is ychyath This is Mansoor ... .... this line size is more than 4 gigs.
```

Output

```
This is Achyuth
This is ychyath
This is Mansoor
. 
. 
.
```

Comment: Have you tried just increasing the JVM heap space?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes Increased the size to around 32g for loading 4 gigs file

Comment: Why so large? Do you have that much on a single machine?

Comment: Yes we have memory, The entire file is a single line, spark or hadoop uses the new line charter to process them as new line. I am struck there

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want other than reading the whole line at once... `BufferedReader` has more methods than just `readLine()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach works if the file size is a multiple of the split size and the character encoding is fixed-length (ASCII, UTF-16, UTF-32, no code points above 127 in UTF-8 or similar...).

Given file

```
This is AchyuthThis is ychyathThis is Mansoor
```

```
val rdd = spark
  .sparkContext
  .binaryRecords(path, 15)
  .map(bytes => new String(bytes))
val df = spark.createDataset(rdd)
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+
|          value|
+---------------+
|This is Achyuth|
|This is ychyath|
|This is Mansoor|
+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Spark doesn't have the option of setting EOL delimiter for text file.

The best way to handle this for me is to use [Setting textinputformat.record.delimiter in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17692857/setting-textinputformat-record-delimiter-in-spark) you will get a lot of options.